# SecurityContext->isGranted() working in controller but not in service

Tags: symfony, security-context

I have a public area of my app accesible with no login or authentication, and when I run this code in a controller `if ($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'))` I get a `true` as expected.

Then I have a service defined like this:

```
main.services:
    class: App\MainBundle\Services\MainServices
    arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @security.context, @service_container ]
```

But when I run this code:

```
public function __construct(EntityManager $em, SecurityContext $securityContext, Container $container) {
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->securityContext = $securityContext;

    error_log("MAIN");
    if ($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'))
        error_log("MAIN Anon");
    else
        error_log("MAIN no anon");
}
```

I get an exception:

> Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException' with message 'The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.'

The service is invoked right after the first command in controller.

Thank you

Comment: This error could occur when service initializes before security token created. Try not to check access in constructor, move this check to method, called from your controller.

Comment: That was it, if you write a response I'll mark it as answer. Thank you @Ziumin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error could occur when service initializes before security token created. Try not to check access in constructor, move this check to method, called from your controller.

Answer (score 2):

Use it only if a token is defined and @Ziumin is wright.

```
public function __construct(EntityManager $em, SecurityContext $securityContext, Container $container) {
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->securityContext = $securityContext;

    error_log("MAIN");

    $token = $this->securityContext->getToken();

    if (is_object($token)) {
        if ($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'))
            error_log("MAIN Anon");
        else
            error_log("MAIN no anon");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good point, the problem itself was for using this in constructor, but anyway you code is a good test to avoid error